# Como fazer uma transição automática entre divs no JQUery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quero fazer uma transição automática entre divs.

Exemplo:

div1 - `show();` 
div2 - `hide();`

.... 3000milisegundoss...

div1 - `hide();`
div2 - `show();`

E fique nessa transição...

Estou tentando fazer desta forma, coloquei em um `toggle()`ele executa apenas uma vez e para.

Como fazer que esta transição fique automática/"infinita"?

```js
$(function(){

  var div1 = $('.cliente1');
  var div2 = $('.cliente2');
  

  $(document).ready(function(){
     div1.show();
     div2.hide();

   setInterval(function(){
       div1.toggle();
       div2.toggle();     
   }, 3000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside class="clients cliente1" style="border: 1px solid black">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

            DIV 1
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <a>
                        Conteúdo DIV 1
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <a>
                        Conteúdo DIV 1
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <a>
                        Conteúdo DIV 1
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <a>
                        Conteúdo DIV 1
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>

    <aside class="clients cliente2" style="border: 1px solid black">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            DIV 2
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <a> 
                        Conteúdo  DIV 2
                    </a> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <a>
                       Conteúdo  DIV 2
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <a>
                        Conteúdo  DIV 2
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <a>
                        Conteúdo  DIV 2
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Zkk parece que seu código está fazendo o que você quer, alternar entre div1 e div2.

No entanto, parece mais certo, encadear o desaparecimento e a exibição das divs 1 e 2. Isso te dá a possibilidade de fazer uma transição mais suave, só exibindo uma div quando a outra desaparecer por completo, assim:

```js
$(function() {
  var div1 = $('.cliente1')
  var div2 = $('.cliente2')
  var escondida=div1, exibida=div2  
    
  $(document).ready(function(){
    exibida.show()
    escondida.hide()

    setInterval(function() {
      exibida.hide("fast", function() {
         // Neste ponto, "exibida" já se escondeu.
         // Exibir a "escondida"
         escondida.show("fast")  
         // Agora trocar "escondida" com a "exibida"
         temp = escondida
         escondida = exibida
         exibida = temp
      })
    }, 3000)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside class="clients cliente1" style="border: 1px solid black">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            DIV 1
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <a>Conteúdo DIV 1</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <a>Conteúdo DIV 1</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <a>Conteúdo DIV 1</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <a>Conteúdo DIV 1</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>

    <aside class="clients cliente2" style="border: 1px solid black">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
            DIV 2
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <a>Conteúdo DIV 2</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <a>Conteúdo DIV 2</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <a>Conteúdo DIV 2</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                    <a>Conteúdo DIV 2</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </aside>
```

Comment: Ficou bem melhor. Muito mais suave. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Viva,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout
http://www.cprogressivo.net/2013/03/O-que-sao-e-como-usar-funcoes-recursivas-em-linguagem-C.html

Ao iniciar deixe uma div com a class hide e outra sem a class hide, pode fazer isso com js ou quando vai apresentar a pagina.. depois corre o codigo:

```
function changeDiv(){

        var div1 = $('.cliente1');
        var div2 = $('.cliente2');

        div1.toggleClass('hide');
        div2.toggleClass('hide');

        setTimeout(changeDiv(),300);
}

changeDiv();
```

Penso que seja isso que quer, qualquer coisa avise ;)

Abraço e boa sorte :)

Comment: Não é necessário rsrs. Encontrei o erro. A função a ser usada não é a `setTimeout`, mas sim a `setInterval` :)

Comment: Mesmo assim, obrigado pela ajuda!